# How to unnest functions in javaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I need some help to understand nested function in javaScript. So, below is a fictional script with nested functions, can somebody help me to understand how to unnest them ?

```
    function start (){

        document.ontouchmove = function1;

        document.onmouseup = function3 = function2; 

    };


    function function1 (){

        //code

    };


    function function2 (){

        // code

    };


    function function3 (){

        //code

    };
```

Comment: Where are the nested functions?

Comment: Please define `unset function`? Do you mean `delete function1;`?

Comment: Nesting functions is not uncommon in JavaScript. Why do you want to unnest them?

Comment: aha, so I misunderstood what nested functions are.

Comment: A nested function basically is a function defined inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

There are no nested functions in your code snippet.

You are using assignment as an expression though, using its return value to 'chain' assignments.

Unchaining the assignment would simply amount to

```
function3 = function2;
document.onmouseup = function3;
```